# Symfony3 api - unable to get data passed by react app and return it using FOSBundle

Tags: php, json, symfony, fosrestbundle

I am making simple symfony api and react app. My react app sends data in json format to the symfony api. However I am unable to access the data that is being sent.

Here is the function in the component in my react app -

```
  createProduct (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    if(this.state.name.length === 0 ){
      this.error = 'Name cannot be empty'
    }else if(this.state.price === 0){
      this.error = 'Price cannot be 0'
    }else if(this.state.price < 0 ){
      this.error = 'Price cannot be negative'
    }else {
      let data = []
      data['name'] = this.state.name
      data['price'] = this.state.price
      ProductActions.addProduct(data)
    }
  }
```

and here is the actual `addProduct` action -

```
 addProduct (data) {
    console.log('made it')
    let request = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/product/post',
      data: JSON.stringify(data),
      contentType: 'application/json'
    }
    $.ajax(request)
      .done(data => this.addProductSuccess(data))
      .fail(err => this.addProductFail(err))
  }
```

And now the Symfony api - here is the action taking care of creating new product

```
/**
     * Creates a new product entity.
     * @Rest\Post("/post")
     */
    function newAction(Request $request ) {

        $body = $request->getContent();
        $body = json_decode($body,true);
        var_dump($body);
        dump($body);
        $logger = $this->get('logger');
        $logger->error($request);
        //$productPrice = $body['price'];
        //$product = new Product($productName,$productPrice);
        //$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        //$em->persist($product);
        //$em->flush();
        //$data['data'] = $product;
        $data['body'] = $body;
        return $data;
    }
```

As you can see most of the code is in comments. The reason being it doesnot work. After this line of code everything breaks

```
$productPrice = $body['price'];
```

And here is the error I receive

> Undefined index: price"

This code was working fine and I was able to get the data in the context of the request easily, but I decided to start using FOSBundle and now it doesn't work.

As you can see there is `var_dump($request)` as well as `dump($request)` in attempts to view the Request being sent.I have also as you can see tried returning the request to my react api to view it there but it doesnot work and this is the error I get -

> Resources are not supported in serialized data

And if it matters - I have before that tried returning `new View($data,{some response code})` however it gives this error -

> Unknown key "request" for annotation "@FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\View

which I have no idea what it means. It says this for everything.If I send normal array it will say `Unknown key '0'` and I have no annotations such as @View and to be honest I have no idea how to use them.

And after those attempts to view the request didn't work I used the `$logger`. Here is what is actually being sent

> POST /product/post HTTP/1.1 Accept:          */* Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8 Connection:      keep-alive Content-Length:  2 Content-Type:    application/json Host:            127.0.0.1:8000 Origin:          http://localhost:3000 Referer:         http://localhost:3000/ User-Agent:      Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Mobile Safari/537.36 X-Php-Ob-Level:  1  [] [] []

I am unable to view the Request in any other manner.

I have seen tutorials that suggest having Symfony FormType to handle submits, but the thing is I have no front-end part and no forms being created in the first place to be submitted. This symfony API is only back-end I am not sure how to send the data from my react app to the symfony api if I was to use symfony forms.

Can someone please tell me how to get the data from the request and how to return it since `return new View({any data}, {some response code})` gives `Unknown key {whatever key I have sent}`?

Comment: Have you tried dumping request data before actually sending request(on frontend)? Does it look exactly like you expect?

Comment: I havent dumped the request in the front-end as I don't think it would help. As mentioned in the question - before using FOSBundle this code worked with the same request being sent. this `$request->getContent()` worked just fine but after changing to FOSBundle and using FOSController and not the usual Symfony controller this doesnot work. I don't know why.

Comment: @svgrafov - after further expection in the front-end I noticed that when I create data for some reason I have made an array and not an object (used `[]` and not `{}` for `data`. Thank you for the advice.I was looking in the wrong place. However I still have one question - how to use @View?When I try `return new View()` whatever I pass to it is unknown key.

Comment: If their documentation is unclear, you can ask separate question about View. I never used FosRest myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Solved (kind of)]** - When creating the data to pass to the symfony api it turned out that for some reason I have written `[]` instead of `{}` and this caused the error in not sending the right values.

However this keeps the other part of the question - how to use @View. Cause whenever I try to return `new View({some data}, {some response code});` it throws an error.